# how to create ForeignKey for username (not userid) in django models.py

Tags: django

I created the following field`models.py`

```
added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and it contained the user Id , but how to make it contain the username instead.

Comment: You can access `username` with `user_id`, Wherever you want to access.

Answer (score 2):

ForeightKey key always reference with an id.If you want to display the username you can do something like `added_by.username`

Comment: my views.py look like this

`
class PaperG(APIView):
      def get(self, request, format=None):
# i could try models.added_by.username or request.username but I don't know how to implement that
            snippets = Post.objects.all()
            serializer = SerlizePaper(snippets, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django Rest Framework, then here's your solution:

```
class Your_Model_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
added_by = serializers.CharField()
class Meta:
    model = Your_Model_Object
    fields = ['added_by']
```

Notice the `added_by =serializers.Charfield()`? That will return the ForeignKey as text not ID.